# Creating WPF Resources in Code Behind and Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ActivityLogs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ActivityLogs="clr-namespace:ActivityLogs"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="900">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ActivityLogs:RightMarginSetter x:Key="RightMarginSetter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="m_gridControl">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" x:Name="messagetype" Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="columnCategory" Width="50*">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>

                        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource RightMarginSetter}, ConverterParameter=20}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">Category</TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=Header.BorderBrush.Color.ColorContext}"></ComboBox>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recorded Time" x:Name="columnDateTime" Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Error Code" x:Name="columnErrorCode" Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tool" x:Name="columnToolId" Width="10*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" x:Name="columnUserId" Width="10*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hi Above one is my XAML Code of My XAML Expression.
i just rewritten it completely in C# (Code behind).

I was unable to create a Static Resource and Bind it with Width Property as i did in XAML.
here my static resource is RightMarginSetter,a class created by me which inherits IValueConverter

Simply i am getting problem while rewriting following part in C#

```
<Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=columnCategory, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource RightMarginSetter}, ConverterParameter=20}">
```

Can you help me out?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way to add converter to `Resources` of current Window :

```
//create converter instance
var converterInstance = new RightMarginSetter();
//add the converter to window resources
this.Resources.Add("RightMarginSetter", converterInstance);
```

Then you can use that resource in binding :

```
//set up binding to use converter in resources
Binding myBinding = new Binding("ActualWidth")
                        {
                            ElementName = "columnCategory",
                            Converter = (RightMarginSetter)this.Resources["RightMarginSetter"],
                            ConverterParameter = 20
                        };
myGrid.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: no exception,no run time error..
converter(RightMarginSetter) not getting called during run time

Comment: if you run in debug mode, is there any binding error in output window?

Comment: i am pretty sure, bz i kept the whole code in try catch,and inside catch i kept a message box with exception message.

Comment: I really suspect there was binding error. This answer only demonstrates translation of specific XAML line you're asking, to C# code. Assuming you managed to port the rest of XAML to C# correctly, this should work fine. I already tested this with simplified scenario.

Comment: check binding error the way I stated in my 2nd comment above. Binding error doesn't throw exception, only print error message in output window.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=columnCategory'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Comment: I am unable to set Name Property on DataGridTextColumn Object. That's why Data Binding Failing.